# TensorFlow: Convolution Neural Network with non-image input

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am interested in using Tensorflow for training my data for binary classification based on CNN.

Now I wonder about how to set the filter value, number of output nodes in the convolution process.

I have read many tutorials and example. However, most of them use image data and I cannot compare it with my data that is customer data, not pixel.

So could you suggest me about this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you data varies in time or space then you can use CNN,I am currently working with EEG data set which varies in time.Also you can refer to this paper
http://www.nlpr.ia.ac.cn/english/irds/People/lwang/M-MCG_EN/Publications/2015/YD2015ACPR.pdf
were the input data(Which is not an image) is presented as an image to the CNN.

Comment: This link does not work anymore... Can you share the pdf with us on another place? Or tell us the title of this work?

Comment: I can still open the link from my computer,the title is 'Skeleton Based Action Recognition with Convolutional Neural Network' @rmd2

Answer (score 2):

You have to reshape the data to be 4d. In this example, I have only 4 column.

```
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0],2, 2,1))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0],2,2, 1))
```

This is a good example to use none image data
https://github.com/fengjiqiang/LSTM-Wind-Speed-Forecasting
You just need to change the following :

prediction_cols

feature_cols

features

and dataload

Comment: The Github doesn't give where to download it's sample data.

Comment: You can find it here http://www.willfleury.com/machine-learning/forecasting/lstm/2017/09/01/short-term-forceasting-lstm.html

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial for text :

[Here !](http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/)

Answer (score 0):

You might use one of following classes:

- class **Dataset**: Represents a potentially large set of elements.
- class **FixedLengthRecordDataset**: A Dataset of fixed-length records
  from one or more binary files.
- class **Iterator**: Represents the state of iterating through a Dataset.
- class **TFRecordDataset**: A Dataset comprising records from one or more 
  TFRecord files.
- class **TextLineDataset**: A Dataset comprising lines from one or more
  text files.

[Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets)

[official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data)